# Is it possible to install mysql 5.7 on Amazon Linux AMI?

Tags: mysql, aws, amazon-linux

I tried installing and I am seeing the error

```
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.17-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
       Requires: systemd
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I also removed all previous installations. How can I fix this?

Comment: Last time I checked AMI does not run `systemd` hence the error. Try `sudo yum clean all` followed by `sudo yum update` before trying again to install MySQL

Comment: Thanks Rui. Here's what I tried :                                                               yum remove mysql-server
    yum remove "mysql*"
    sudo yum update
    killall mysqld; killall mysqld_safe
    yum localinstall https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el5-7.noarch.rpm
    yum install mysql-community-server

I am still seeing the error
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.17-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: systemd

Comment: Please add to the question the details. If you are using mysql/Oracle repos you should select generic-linux for AMI boxes and not RH packages. File also a bug/request with Oracle for AMI rpm packages, please. Check also what versions can you find in AMI repositories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using mysql/Oracle repos you should select `Linux-generic` in the [Download MySQL Community Server page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) for AMI boxes and not RedHat/Fedora packages.

Last time I checked AMI does not run `systemd` hence the error.  While in past you could somewhat get away with installing RH packages in AMI Linux, nowadays with the convergence of Linux versions to `systemd` it is ever more difficult to install foreign packages in distributions which do not support `systemd`.

File also a bug/request with Oracle for AMI rpm packages, please.

Check also what versions can you find in AMI repositories, just in case.

Comment: AMI repo has mysql Server version: 5.5 and 5.6

Comment: What about using the rh6 packages? That is what AMI is currently based on...

Comment: if this fails, try flushing the cache and see if it resolves dependency issues here https://serverfault.com/questions/873955/how-solve-mysql-5-7-dependency clean all also suggest sudo rm -rf /var/cache/yum/* , that was required to get it to work for me

Answer (score 1):

okay, I had given the same task to my junior and he referred me this link and said it is not possible to install MySQL5.7 on Amazon AMI. But I tried it is actually possible. You should download the  **mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm** (suitable with CentOS/RHEL 6 OS and install it). After installing the community release when you do

`wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm
yum install mysql-community-server -y`

You will get MySQL5.7 version installed and working on Amazon Linux AMI

Comment: This still gives me a `Requires: systemd` error

Answer (score 1):

As of sometime since 2017, Amazon has provided a compatible MySQL 5.7 package.

```
yum install mysql57-server
```

If you are updating an existing MySQL 5.5 installation, you will most likely need to

```
mysql_upgrade --force -uroot -p
```

at least once, and then stop and restart mysqld.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Linux does not support systemd, so if any package requires systemd to be installed first, that package will not be installed.

I would suggest that you use CentOS or another RHEL-based distribution instead which has full support for SystemD and therefore will not experience the same issues.

Comment: WarGames...old ;)... If I were the OP I would prefer to use AMI in AWS, as it is better supported and you can find lot of specific how tos for it. I would also prefer going the Debian/Ubuntu route if not using AMI (we do not know the OP preferences to be fair). Your answer while technically correct, fails to address directly the question.